# Invalid image error using dataUrl in pdfmake

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, pdfmake

I'm using pdfmake to generate a PDF doc in an angular app, and just trying to add an image to the output using a dataURL (following the [pdfmake docs](http://pdfmake.org/index.html#/gettingstarted).

```
        var docDefinition = {
          content: [
            {
              table: {
                widths: ['*'],
                body: [
                  [{text: 'Table text goes here', style: 'tableCellPadded'}]
                ]
              },
            },
            {
              image: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJgAAACHCAYAAADqQ...AABJRU5ErkJggg==",
              width: 152
            }
            '...various other text lines go here...'
          ],
          styles: {
            header: {
              bold: true,
              fontSize: 14
            },
            tableCellPadded: {
              margin: [0, 15, 0, 15],
              bold: true,
              fontSize: 14
            },
            note: {
              fontSize: 16,
              bold: true,
              italics: true
            }
          }
        };
```

However, when I attempt to print out the doc, I get this error in my console:

> invalid image, images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)

As best as I can tell, I have the item entered correctly in the doc definition object, and my dataURL is valid (I've tested it in my browser). Is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: missing quote?.

Comment: I thought about that, but I did double check that.

Comment: I mean you're missing a quote here: `image: data:image/png;b..` it should be  rather `image: "data:image/png;...."`

Comment: What result do you get if you don't base64 encode and just pass the file path / name ?

Comment: @MehulMohan, Yeah, that was a copy/paste error. Thanks, I fixed in in the post and verified it was correct in my code.

Comment: @floor I get the same error no matter which path I try.

Comment: That image content does not look like base64.  Did you actually convert it to base64?

Comment: I had the same error, and the solution for me was to use png image instead of svg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I'm chalking this one up to an ID-10-T error. My line with the base64 encoded URL is working fine. I found another line farther down in my doc definition object where I wasn't referring to the image properly, and that one was throwing the error.

Answer (score 7):

You can try like this and it will work fine.

```js
getBase64ImageFromURL(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "anonymous");

    img.onload = () => {
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;

      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

      resolve(dataURL);
    };

    img.onerror = error => {
      reject(error);
    };

    img.src = url;
  });
}
```

```js
async createPdf() {
  var docDefinition = {
    content: [
      {
        image: await this.getBase64ImageFromURL("../../assets/ribbonLogo1.png")
       },
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It's always better to explain briefly how the code is solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

pdfMake will only work for .jpeg / .jpg / .png files,
make sure your image file is one of this file extensions.

Very important.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this bug within a React environment.

The problem seems to be a mutation of the arguments object that get passed to createPdf.

I fixed it by ensuring what is passed into createPdf is "clean" and has no references to the data that is coming in anymore. This is my code:

```
      useEffect(() => {

        const iframe = iframeRef.current;
            
        pdfMake
        .createPdf({
            content: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(content))
        })
        .getBase64((encodedString) => {
            iframeRef.current.src = `data:application/pdf;base64,${encodedString}`;
        })

        return () => iframe.src = 'about:blank';

      }, [content]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with adding image path in docDefinition object. You can check the Image documentation https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/images/

Be sure to add:

```
images: {
    mySuperImage: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,...content...',
};
```

like this.